# local-storage javascript : How can I split 1 JSON containing 2 object into 2 JSON (1 per object?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I store user's basket in localStorage (he can have more than one item) :

```
 let data = [];
 for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    let info = {
      "price": price,
      "quantity": quantity,
      "priceTotal": priceTotal
    };
    data.push(JSON.stringify(info));
  }
  localStorage.setItem("reservations", data);
}
```

if the user got two items, my json look like that :

```
{"price":"10 €", "quantity":"1", "priceTotal":"10 €"},{"price":"20 €", "quantity":"2", "priceTotal":"40 €"}
```

I print it in console log with :

```
let info = localStorage.getItem("reservations");
console.log(info);
```

As I understand, this print it as a String.
I'm trying to make it an Object to use the data somewhere else with  `myObject[propertyName]` but when 
I try to `PARSE` with `getItem()` :

```
  let myObject = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('reservations'));
```

I receive an error :

> VM8224:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 123
>       at JSON.parse ()

Is it due to the fact that there is 2 Objects in my Json ?
How can I split the objects ?

I made a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Demky/4ea1s3rn/28/
(you need to open console to see result)

- save data
- read dada
- crash when it try to json.parse

  > VM516:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 51
  >   at JSON.parse`

let me know if I can make my question more clear.

Comment: Your JSON data needs to be enclosed in an array.

Comment: See the correction here https://jsfiddle.net/n19vbydq/ Since it was a small mistake, I don't prefer giving this as an answer.

Comment: Stringify the whole array instead of the individual items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 let data = [];
 for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    let info = {
      "price": price,
      "quantity": quantity,
      "priceTotal": priceTotal
    };
    data.push(info);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("reservations", JSON.stringify(data));
}

let myObject = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('reservations'));
```

> localStorage.setItem does not let you store objects. So instead you should stringify the whole object and then get it. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

When you store array in local storage you need to first stringify that data then store.
Like this.

```html
localStorage.setItem("reservations", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stringify the whole Array instead of each item of the array while storing it in localstorage.

```
 let data = [];
 for (i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    let info = {
      "price": price,
      "quantity": quantity,
      "priceTotal": priceTotal
    };
    data.push(info);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("reservations", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Here's [the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fscLzyv/)